# jQuery If children of element have two classes - do something

Tags: jquery

I want to catch if children of element have two classes, so for example if we have something like this:

HTML

```
<div class="mainElement">
  <div>
    <p class="thisClass">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="andThisClass">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to catch it and remove it, for example like this:

jQuery

```
if($('.mainElement').hasClasses('thisClass, andThisClass') ){
$('.mainElement').css('display', 'none');
```

}

Though this obviously wouldn't work, I've also tried with **.find()**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `.find`

Try like this

```
if ($('.mainElement').find('.thisClass').length>0 && $('.mainElement').find('.andThisClass').length>0) {
  console.log("contain");
}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/wu7x3f8m/)**</kbd>

you didn't close your tag properly

here

```
    </p>
  </div  <- here
  <div>
    <div>
```

Comment: Thanks, both answers do what they should, but I'm gonna give 'correct' to you because you are using **if** in your example

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with [`has`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) filter,

```
var cache = $('.mainElement');
cache.toggle(!(cache.has('.thisClass').length && cache.has('.andThisClass').length));
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wu7x3f8m/1/)